Tail of $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\min_{i} x_i}$
I have a sequence of independent and i.i.d. random variables  $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{n}$, where each $x_i$ is positive, has finite expectation $\mu$, and is drawn from a distribution with a bounded density $\rho$. For example, it could be $|N(0,1)|$ or uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. I’m interested in the following ratio:
$$R_n = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i}{\min_{i} x_i}$$
I want to analyze the upper bound of $R_n$. But since $1/x_i$ is possible to have an infinite expectation, I do not believe I can get a finite expectation upper bound result. Now I am very interested in the following question:

How can the tail of $R_n$ be analyzed? Can I get a non-asymptotic probabilistic upper bound of $R_n$

I’m particularly interested in the bound with the smallest dependence on $n$. (Getting the tightest dependence on $\rho$ and $\mu$ is not the most important.) Any insights, references, or ideas on how to approach these questions would be greatly appreciated.
